# File system based persistence or MSMQ

Tags: .net, persistence, messaging, msmq

So in a legacy project i work on the following strategy is used for data(large amounts) persistence.It was working fine upto a point but now looks like it has hit its limits. I am considering a design change but unsure of what to do.

So today the following happens,
There is a ASMX WebService that receives files from various clients and writes them to the filesystem following a folder scheme.
A windows service keeps watching the folder for changes and reads files entering the folder and based off that parses the file and writes data to the database.

Now what we are seeing is files keep piling up in the folder and the windows service is overwhelmed with reading and saving them. Its no like freezing or anything but just way behind in terms of data persistence. Like 36 hours late.

I am wondering whether i should remove the intermediary file saving , file reading code which is legacy code and hence not concurrent or asynchronous and replace that with a more "standard" messagequeue impl that will most likely be better performing.

In that case the web service can be replaced with the message queue and the windows service can read messages and parse and save them to the database.
I am looking for ideas on how such cases can be analyzed.

Comment: Your requirements are an absolutely perfect use case for message queueing.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking for confirmation. I am right now working on a POC using ApacheMQ. Messaging must be so much better in terms of performance as the messages must be loaded from memory instead of what we do today by reading from the file and loading to memory ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what we are seeing is files keep piling up in the folder and the
>   windows service is overwhelmed with reading and saving them. Its no
>   like freezing or anything but just way behind in terms of data
>   persistence. Like 36 hours late.

This strikes me as potentially a problem with your file processing code rather than anything inherently wrong with the transport. If your file processing code is performing badly then swapping out one transport for another won't really help. I assume for the purposes of this question that you have optimised the file processing code already in response to this problem.

> I am wondering whether i should remove the intermediary file saving ,
>   file reading code which is legacy code and hence not concurrent or
>   asynchronous and replace that with a more "standard" messagequeue impl
>   that will most likely be better performing.

So I can detect an expectation here that by swapping out the transport you suspect of the being the problem, you will solve the problem. I'm not saying this assumption is incorrect but it should be considered that reading files in Windows is generally really, really fast. I would be surprised in fact to find that your IO cost is the thing which is causing your processing to slow down. Consider also that replacing file transport with MQ transport will still require reading files from disk - where do you think the MQ subsystem [stores the items](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/GuaranteedMessaging.html) while they're on the queue?

> In that case the web service can be replaced with the message queue
>   and the windows service can read messages and parse and save them to
>   the database.

That said, if you really have optimised your file processing process and files are still queuing up in the folder for long periods of time before being processed, a modern message queueing imeplementation will give you some benefit. As you alluded to before I assume that the file reading process is single threaded. I assume so because managing filesystem locking in a multithreaded environment is not fun. With message queuing many of the message consumer client libraries come with the [competing consumers](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html) pattern built in, so scaling out the number of threads (or the number of queue reader windows services) is much easier.

Comment: So following are reasons i can think of i would want to shift to some queueing system. i. Scalability/Asynch   ii. Reliability - Expecting the Queueing service to take care of recovery iii. The service would optimize memory a lot better than our application code currently does. In that a lot of data would be read off of memory than doing IO.

Comment: Remember that MSMQ is not made to handle large files as there is a 4 MB size limit on the messages.